# Trouble getting java methods combined in one main method

Tags: java, methods, accessor, mutators

```
class Bug {

// An ant is represented by the coordinates of its location,
// and the direction it is facing.
Integer x;
Integer y;
Dir dir;

enum Dir { E,W,N,S }
}

Bug(Integer x, Integer y, Dir dir) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dir = dir;
}}

class BugWorld {


Integer theBreadth, theHeight;
Board board;
Bug bug;

BugWorld(Integer breadth, Integer height) {
    board = new board(breadth, height);
    bug = new Bug(breadth/2, height/2, Ant.Direction.Y);
    theBreadth = breadth;
    theHeight = height;
}
```

I already have the following:

```
Status status(Integer x, Integer y) {
    return board[x][y];
}


void update(Integer x, Integer y) {
    board[x][y].next();
}
```

This part below is where I'm having some trouble:

```
/* Take the world of the bug to the next step. */
void step() {
    // 1) Get the state at the present bug position.
          //I've done the following (next line) so far.
           Bug status(Integer x, Integer y); ...?

    // 2) Change the 'status' at that position.
             .............?
}
```

It's just combining these that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve and what is not working?

Comment: @jootschouten The Status consists of two Enum {Visited, NotVisited}. What I want to achieve is highlighted in the last block of code. The line just below the text "//I've done the following (next line) so far." is not working.

Comment: @jootschouten what I want to do is move the bug from one place on the `board` to another (in the long run). The `board` consists of coordinates (x,y). `next()` changes the status from `NotVisited` to `Visited` or vice versa depending which one is the initial.

Comment: Can I ask, why are you using Integer instead of int throughout?

Comment: Bug status(Integer x, Integer y); is meaningless.  Even if there is a missing dot, status is not a static method, and you're not catching the returned value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to do, but I think here's what you want

```
void step(){

     //get the location of the bug 
     int x = bug.x;
     int y = bug.y;

     //gets the status of the location of the bug
     Status s = status(x,y);

     //move the bug, or do something based on the status of the place

     //update the status of the location the bug was originally on
     update(x,y)
}
```

Comment: No, I'm not trying to create a new bug object, I'm just trying to firstly obtain the `status` at the present location of the bug on the board at the given (x,y) coordinate and then in the second part, change the 'status' at that position. The Bug constructor is now highlighted above.

Comment: so does my code not do what you want? The first line gets the status at the location of the bug, and the next line changes it no?

Comment: The first one didn't seem to until I put in the following:

Status status = board.status(bug.x,bug.y);

Comment: are your status(x,y) and update(x,y) methods in the same Class as the step() method?